# Elliptically Distrbuted Numerical Data

Tags: data-request, research

I  am doing a research about outlier detection in Multivariate Elliptically Shaped Numerical data and I have searched a lot for a matching dataset yet I couldn't find any. Any help will be appreciated in finding such dataset.

I mean if you visualize the data (in two dimensions) you would see the data points form an elliptic shape.

Comment: If you can explain in plain English what "multivariate elliptically shaped numerical data" means, that would increase the chances of getting good recommendations.

Comment: Sure, I do mean if you actually visualize the data (two dimension)  you would see the data points form an elliptic shape.

Comment: The planets move in nearly planar approximately elliptical orbits, but I'm not sure if that counts as "data", since it's highly predictable.

Answer (score 1):

**This answer may not fully answer your question.**

Have you seen the [Plot a confidence ellipse of a two-dimensional dataset](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/statistics/confidence_ellipse.html)? Here they use plotting an ellipse for a two-dimensional dataset.

or if you are looking for data points to plot

you can use the parametric equation of an ellipse and generate random datapoints

`x = u+a.cos(t) ; y = v+b.sin(t)`

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import pi

u=1.     #x-position of the center
v=0.5    #y-position of the center
a=2.     #radius on the x-axis
b=1.5    #radius on the y-axis

t = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
plt.plot( u+a*np.cos(t) , v+b*np.sin(t) )
plt.grid(color='lightgray',linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Which gives :

[image]